# What are the details needed to receive euros from my company in Germany to a bank account in India

Tags: india, money-transfer, international-transfer, eur-euro

I want to receive Euros from my company in Germany to my savings bank account (HDFC) in India where I work. What are the exact details I have to give to my company in Germany? My company's bank is Deutsche Bank.

Swift code of HDFC which is HDFCINBBXXX, Bank Name & Address and Account Number are sufficient for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its best to check with your company what details they need. Generally for SWIFT Transfers,
the below is sufficient;

- Bank Name
- Bank Address
- SWIFT BIC
- Your Bank Account Number
- Your Name

Additionally any transfers to India require a "Purpose of Remittance" to be filled by the company paying to money.

Comment: what should be filled in "purpose of remittance" ?

Comment: Its why money is being sent to you ... Salary/Fee/invoice etc. Its best your company checks with their Bankers and fill in the right information.